# Spring create bean on loop

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have list of names for bean to be created.

```
List<String> beanNames = getNames();
```

And I want to create Spring beans on loop with this names;

This is bean that I want to create.

```
@Bean(“beanName”)//bean name must be iterated value of beanNames
public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(getHost());
    jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(getPort());
    jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jedisConnectionFactory;
}
```

And then I want to get any RedisConnectionFactory by name like :

```
RedisConnectionFactory rcf = applicationContext.getBean(“a name from beanNames list");
```

İs that possible?

Comment: you should consider pooling capability instead of autowiring bean. connectionFactory which has connection pooling capability by default.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569901/use-connection-pool-with-jedis

Comment: @CodeIsLife my main problem is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545572/spring-data-redis-with-multi-tenancy . I have been trying to implement multitenancy.

Comment: answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51547333/2371309